# How to install hp scanjet 200 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, scanner, xsane

Unable to scan with hp scan-jet 200. When I type `lsusb` command in terminal it shows the scanner details.

I opened the simple scan which displays no scanners found, and x sane image scanners also displays the same error.

Comment: have you configured your printer?

Comment: not yet its not a printer its a scanner

Comment: alright, you should go to system settings, printing, and add your scanner to it. hopefully on configuration, it should start working.

Comment: I have the same problem. I only see an option there to add a printer , not a scanner ?

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: Well still add the scanner as a printer?

Comment: According to this site, there are generally no drivers for scanner-only HP devices on linux: http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

Comment: A similar issue has been reported [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/461184/hp-scanjet-4890-does-not-work-properly-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: I don't have one, but you could try if it is compatible with one of the other scanjet models that are supported (genesys driver!), and maybe you only need to force using the other driver. Can you try `sane-find-scanner -v -v`  and edit your question with the output here, please?

Comment: More precisely, I suspect the device to be a genesys `GL84_` chip; and other devices with this chip series apparently *are* supported. If you look at the end of https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/sane/sane-backends.git/tree/backend/genesys_devices.c all you *may* need is to do a similar mapping of USB id to a few model settings. I'd try with the `hpn6310_model` as initial guess (HP ScanJet N6310). But try at your own risk, maybe as the genesys developers for instructions.

Comment: dmesg finds the model and serial number; but, scanimage -L says the scanner is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

There are no drivers available for the ScanJet 200, be it open or proprietary.

The ***only*** way to use your scanner would be to install windows in a virtualbox and scan from there.