# HP Scanjet 4890 does not work properly in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hp, scanner, xsane

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and was setting up the peripherals. All went well and the scanner was recognized right away though as a Scanjet 4850C instead of a 4890.

I tried simple scan and only got black. I tried various settings and with a fresh start of Simple Scan, I was able to scan at 150dpi greyscale only. I read some helps on the web and they suggested XSane. I installed that and can now scan in both colour and greyscale but still only at 150dpi. Any other resolution results only in a black image.

Any help would be appreciated. I think this is a bug that many need some updates.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try hplip tools from Ubuntu Applications Center or from http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I finally bit the bullet and paid $79.95 for the VuScan software.  It seams to be the only scanner software for Ubuntu 14.04 that actually works with both scanners I have tried on Ubuntu (Hp 4850) and Epson L210 printer/scanner.

Its quite a high price, and I think it should be more like $30 given the fact that scanners themselves are around that price) but at least it works!